# Flow of posting UDP packet with CoreFoundation

Tags: objective-c, sockets, udp

I'm writing code that sends an UDP packet using CoreFoundation. Here is the code

```
CFSocketRef socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, 0u, NULL, NULL);
// ... (handle error if socket is NULL)

struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;
// ... (set fields of sockaddr)
NSData *addressData = [NSData dataWithBytes: &sockaddr length: sockaddr.sin_len];

if (CFSocketSendData(self.socket, (__bridge CFDataRef) addressData, (__bridge CFDataRef) data, 0) != kCFSocketSuccess) {
    // ... (handle error)
}
```

However, I am not sure, how to complete this flow, i.e. I have the following questions:

- Should I close / release the socket somehow if I am not going to send more data? If so, is `CFSocketInvalidate` the appropriate function?
- The documentation to `CFSocketSendData` says: "If this function returns kCFSocketSuccess, then by the time it returns, the data has been queued in the socket buffer for delivery." Can I invalidate the socket right after calling `CFSocketSendData` or should I wait until the data are send?
- If there is a need to wait, how can I find out that the data are already sent? Can I find out if there were any errors? (Of course, I have no guarantee that receiver gets the data with UDP. However, can I detect some errors which occur on my side during sending?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I close / release the socket somehow if I am not going to send more data? If so, is CFSocketInvalidate the appropriate function?

Yes. Call `CFSocketInvalidate` followed by `CFRelease`.

> Can I invalidate the socket right after calling CFSocketSendData or should I wait until the data are send?

In the [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1151.16/CFSocket.c), `CFSocketSendData` calls `sendto` with the `SO_SNDTIMEO` option set.

There's no need to wait. If `CFSocketSendData` returns `kCFSocketSuccess`, you're done.

Note that this situation can be [more complicated](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable) for a TCP connection.

> However, can I detect some errors which occur on my side during sending?

You can. Using `errno`. The possible errors for `sendto` are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sendto.2.html).

Comment: Testing return value of `sendto` for errors is fine. From the documentation to `CFSocketSendData`: "If this function returns `kCFSocketSuccess`, then by the time it returns, the data has been queued in the socket buffer for delivery." This means that if the function returns, the app is done with sending the packet but there is still something to be done for the system. Can the app find out that the system is also done, i.e. that the packet has really been sent from the device?

Comment: @Cimlman Never tried it myself, but it looks like [SO_NWRITE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) is what you want. [You can see some sample code near the bottom of this source file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cups/cups-372/cups/test/ipptool.c).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `SO_NWRITE`. I have tried it on iOS 8.4. Although `getsockopt` with `SO_NWRITE` returns 0, i.e. no error, the buffered byte count is always zero (even if called immediately after `CFSocketSendData`). Not sure if it means that the data transfer is fairly quick or that getting the buffered data size is not implemented on iOS.